# Am I implementing Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN) exactly as I intended?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am feeding following input data: (see image)
[image]

Conceptually, I need to apply a filter in such a way that a circle is drawn in the image (in the direction of arrow).
I need to use the 2D Convolution Layer with a filter size of 5*1.

**my code**

```
input_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape, name="Time_Series_analysis") # input shape is: Tensor("Time_Series_Activity:0", shape=(?, 24, 6, 1), dtype=float32) 
con_l1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 1), activation="relu")(input_layer) # Tensor("conv2d/Relu:0", shape=(?, 20, 6, 64), dtype=float32)
```

Would you kindly confirm that I implemented the code exactly as I conceptualized it (in the diagram)?  If this is incorrect, kindly correct me.

Comment: Can you share any more of your code for context, please?

Comment: @JamesGeddes what you required more, either next layer or what?

Comment: If I understood correctly what you are trying to do, then your code should be fine. You can confirm that by looking at the output shape, which is (20, 6, 64). This means that your filter way applied 20 times on every column for each of the 6 columns.